# UIFont not set text in center

Tags: objective-c, uifont

I try to add this font "BebasNeue Regular.ttf" to my project

And after the label is show I notice that the text not center.

[image]

I try to fix this with :

```
 [mylabel sizeToFit]; // not fix 

  mylabel.textAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;// not fix 

  [mylabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter] // not fix
```

what I do wrong ??

update :

when I instal the font in My mac and open in pages it look fine I guess the font file is ok , but in Xcode its still not work )- :[image]

Comment: When your code runs correct with system font, it must be an error in the font. So the only think you can do is take an other font.

Comment: with open sans everything is ok for example  , but with this BebasNeue Regular.ttf I can't find a good file that works , i try to download a 5-6 font file and Its not work!

Comment: did you try?
[mylabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter]

Comment: yes I try   [mylabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter] But the test still stick to left conor

Comment: import the font to your mac and use it with pages or something else. Then you can see if the font is correct or not.